# Calculate Center of gravity of several triangles

Tags: java, computational-geometry

I cant wrap my mind about how to solve this problem.  I have created 3 triangles:

[image]

I have the XY coordinates of all the individual triangles. I want to calculate the center of gravity if they are put together as shown, but only using the filled part, and wherever they intersec, you do not count the mass twice.  How can I go about doing this in java?

Can I somehow combine these into 1 of some kind of object, and then do a numeric calculation of each area and find a middle ground, or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to solve your mathematical/geometrical problem first - then you write the code...

Comment: Could you please post the code and your equations that you've written trying to solve the problem so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid might help you.

Comment: I found a way to gather it together as an Area (java.awt.geom.Area). Is there a way to find the center of gravity or the middle of this?

Comment: Triangulate the polygon that you obtain. The c.o.g. is the properly weighted (by area) average of the coordinates of the c.o.g.s of the individual triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your shape to a single polygon (there are two intersections to be computed).

Then use the [centroid formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon) for polygons.

Another option is to fill all triangles in the same color (by polygon or seed filling), then seed fill the resultant area, while accumulating the X and Y coordinates on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to determine for what you actually want to compute the center of gravity. Obviously, when the triangles intersect (and the overlapping area should not be counted twice), then you are not computing the center of gravity of triangles, but the center of gravity of their intersection area.

Fortunately, such an intersection area can easily be computed with the `Area` class. And according to one comment, you already have an `Area` describing this area.

So one option to compute the center of gravity of this area is to compute the average of all border points of the `Area`.

**Note that this only works when the `Area` does not have holes**.

Otherwise, you have to compute the area of the `Area`.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class CenterOfGravity
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path2D p0 = new Path2D.Double();
        p0.moveTo(100, 100);
        p0.lineTo(200, 100);
        p0.lineTo(150,  50);
        p0.closePath();

        Path2D p1 = new Path2D.Double();
        p1.moveTo(150, 100);
        p1.lineTo(250, 100);
        p1.lineTo(200,  50);
        p1.closePath();

        Area a = new Area();
        a.add(new Area(p0));
        a.intersect(new Area(p1));

        Point2D cog = computeCenterOfGravity(a);
        System.out.println(cog);
    }

    private static Point2D computeCenterOfGravity(Shape shape)
    {
        return computeAverage(computePoints(shape, 1.0));
    }

    private static Point2D computeAverage(
        Collection<? extends Point2D> points)
    {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        for (Point2D point : points)
        {
            x += point.getX();
            y += point.getY();
        }
        if (!points.isEmpty())
        {
            x /= points.size();
            y /= points.size();
        }
        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

    public static List<Point2D> computePoints(
        Shape shape, double flatness)
    {
        List<Point2D> result = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, flatness);
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        while (!pi.isDone())
        {
            int segment = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            switch (segment)
            {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    result.add(new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]));
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(
                        "Invalid segment in flattened path!");
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```